# Show that change in internal energy equals zero for an adiabatic process with incompressible fluid

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic, energy

I have a problem when solving an exercise in thermodynamics. I am supposed to show that when we have an open system, where the process is adiabatic with an incompressible fluid, it follows that the process has to be isothermic. (meaning that du=0). I don't understand why we can use the equation for the closed system to show this, when we actually have an open system with a reversible pump.

The exercise involves a pump, with fluid flowing in an out of the system. The energy formula for this open system is therefore:

Equation 1: $\frac{dE}{dt}=\dot Q -\dot W +\sum \dot m_i h_{tot,i}-\sum \dot m_e h_{tot,e}$.

My problem is to show that the process is isothermal by only knowing that the process is adiabatic and that the fluid is incompressible.

In the solution to the exercise, is says that it uses the formula below to show this:

Equation 2: $du=dq-d\omega$

Equation 2 is the energy balance equation for a closed system, and I don't understand why we can use this equation to show that $du=0$, when our system is open. 
Does anyone know why this is okay to do?
David

Comment: Seeing the system as open or closed depends on the point of view I would say. If you stay at one point and look at what is coming in and what is coming out, the system is open. If you follow a "fluid particle" during the process, then it can be considered a closed system I think.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a smart way to think of it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any of those formulae. Visualize an ideal fluid element (no viscosity) in its rest frame. If it is incompressible, its volume does not change and all work done on it by pressure forces in any time interval equals change in its kinetic energy. If the flow is also adiabatic, no heat is transferred from one element to another.

Since no work and no heat is being transferred to the element in the frame where the element is at rest, the change in its internal energy is zero. If internal energy is supposed to be function of temperature only, this means that also temperature does not change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This answer was also very helpfull!

Comment: @David, you're welcome. I've rephrased the answer to improve it.